# How can I sync Reminders with Google Tasks?

Tags: data-synchronization, ios, google-sync

I was looking for a way to sync my reminders from Google Calendar with the reminders app in iOS 5.

I have Google Sync set up, and on my "Mail, Contacts, Calendars" settings page, it says "Mail, Contacts, Calendars, Reminders" are being synced with Google Sync, but reminders created on the gmail tasks (or google calendar tasks) do not show up on the phone, and vice versa.

What can I do to get them to sync?

**--update:**

[Macworld says](http://www.macworld.com/article/160435/2011/06/ios5_reminders.html):

> You can also save your tasks to Google Calendar or Exchange servers,
>   which then handle the syncing separately.

But it doesn't say how to do it...

Comment: Please note that enabling Reminders sync for Exchange servers, if unsupported, [seems to drain the battery badly in iOS 5](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27565/why-is-ios-5-draining-my-battery-so-fast/27624#27624).

Comment: To be blunt I think that Macworld article was either overoptimistic or full of crap. A year later and there is no non-hack way to do this, and the hacks to make it work are *ugly*.

Answer (score 10):

As I understand it from http://www.google.com/mobile/sync/ the Google Sync (push-email) doesn't currently support Tasks, so even if the iPhone page says Tasks (as it's using the Exchange protocol) Google won't actually do anything with tasks yet

Comment: sad.. :( "tasks" is the name of a calendar from the google calendar. They could do the sync there..

Comment: I updated the question with a information from the Macworld, looks like there's a way...

Comment: As far as I could find out through trial (and failure), Macworld simply assumed this is so. Google does not seem to expose its tasks calendar ins sync, either via the Exchange or the CalDAV protocol – which means you cannot create a Reminders list on their server. @kgfullerton’s answer (sadly) is correct.

Comment: Ok, so I did synchronized the reminders with iCloud, and the calendar with Google Calendar. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3):

**Update**: Tasket is no longer an option it seems, original answer below.

**Beware**: url now as it leads to suspicious ad-popups.

---

<s>[Tasket](http://tasket.mobi/)</s> seems to be the solution for this problem.

> Your iOS Device (iPhone, iPad, etc.) talks to Tasket, and Tasket talks to your Gmail account. Now you can now use the native Reminders app to manage your Gmail tasks!

Tasket is currently in beta right now,  but it looks very promising.

[image]

Comment: Sadly Tasket is now dead. not sure why... (hosting costs I presume...)

Answer (score 1):

I would have suggested Google Tasks Porter (a Google app which is designed to import/export Google tasks). However, Google Tasks Porter has long been dead.

Tasket also seems dead.

gTasks is not the native iOS Reminders app although it will sync to Google Tasks.

Since tasks from Google calendar do not sync to the iPhone (via Google Sync), I'd conclude that there's currently no way to bring iPhone Reminders app in sync with Google Tasks.