# Short battery life on a brand new iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, battery

Well I got my iPhone 4 about a week ago. When I got it I did several full charging cycles, 3-5 if I remember correctly. And these days an iPhone battery really seemed "unkillable". It was really hard to drain about 50% with wifi and 3g internet, games, photos and videos, music, and several different apps.

But now I experience something strange: my battery drops 30% by night (just locked screen), and when I use my iPhone not so hard as first days (just music and Safari), battery has only 30% remaining (out of 100%) in 5 hrs.

Well, it's very bad. I don't want to charge my iPhone twice a day.

Also, when I leave my iPhone charging for night (I know it can fully charge in 1 hr), I see 93% in the morning. And it doesn't increase.

So, as I said I calibrated my battery several times when got an iPhone, and now battery drains super-fast. Can anybody tell me what's wrong and what should I do to make my battery work as expected (at least 10-15 hrs on hard usage, but 20+ hrs will be welcome :D)?

Hope to hear the solution. I tried setting it up as new already :/

(The original question is on Apple Disscussion Forum https://discussions.apple.com/message/16420171)

Comment: I'm confused - when you mention the iPhone battery "seemed unkillable", is this referring to the same device that is now having battery problems?

Comment: Yeah, I meant it was **really** hard to drain battery full.

Comment: Is it a new device? Also, I think 10-15 hours on hard usage is actually pretty good battery life. Have you added any data hogging apps, setup push email, etc? Any changes since the battery started performing more poorly?

Comment: Yes, it's a new device. I said it **doesn't** work 10-15 hrs, as it was expected. It works 5-6 hrs on **not** hard usage. No changes. It just started draining faster :(

Comment: Ah ok. In that case, if you've already tried doing a restore and that didn't fix the problem, I'd take it back into the Apple Store. Might just have a bum battery.

Comment: iPhone was originally bought in UK by our local shop. We bought it from our local shop... This will really take a while :/ (No Apple Store in my country, Belarus)

Answer (score 1):

Since you've tagged your question with iOS 5, I'm assuming you've updated. Take a look at this question and see if anything there helps: [Why is iOS 5 draining my battery so fast?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27565/why-is-ios-5-draining-my-battery-so-fast)

I had the same issue after updating, and deactivating syncing of Reminders with my work's Exchange server did the trick.

Comment: I have deactivated syncing of Reminders w/ iCloud. And I have no Exchange account, BTW.

Comment: @goshakk It doesn't necessarily have to be an Exchange account from what I've heard, it's enough that it's an account that doesn't have support for reminders. If your iCloud account is the only account on the phone it's likely something else that's the culprit.