# Is it possible to add iCloud Reminders to iCal calendars?

Tags: icloud, ical, calendar, reminders

In iCloud, each Reminder is placed in a named list (called a "List" in the details dialog, and a "Calendar" in the context menu in iCal), but there seems to be no way to assign a reminder to an existing ("normal") iCal calendar (as there was with pre-iCloud "To Do" items).

[image: Reminder calendar context menu in iCal]

*Is there a way to assign a Reminder to an existing iCal calendar?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. With iCloud and its supporting operating systems (iOS 5 and OS X 10.7.2), Apple has split the calendar stores on its online CalDAV servers to be either event-only, or task-only. Reminders sync to task-only calendars. See this [Apple Support article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4969) for some details.

Comment: This is the same reason why you cannot sync reminders with Google Tasks, BTW. See [Question 27480](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/27480/11948).

Comment: Does this also mean that one cannot drag a Reminder into a time slot on the calendar (as one used to be able to do)?

Comment: And (presumably) calling a Reminder list a "Calendar" in the iCal context menu is a bit of a bug.

Comment: Yup to both, though “bug” may be a bit harsh for the second one – I’d call it a UI glitch. Reminders have been shoehorned into iCal with the 10.7.2 upgrade, some rough edges are to be expected. Also keep in mind the terminology is only superficial; technically, both *are* calendars.