# Sync Google Tasks with iOS Reminders?

Tags: gmail, reminders

Is there anyway of syncing my Google/Gmail tasks with iOS reminders?

Comment: When I made the sync, I used Beesy on iPad. Now Reminders is sync with tasks as Yahoo Tasks, Outlook.. Keep an eye maybe you'll find how to do.

Answer (score 4):

I've created a service called [Tasket](http://Tasket.mobi) which Syncs iOS Reminders with Gmail Tasks.  I do this by emulating a Microsoft Exchange server - iOS supports syncing Reminders with Exchange.

Tasket is currently in beta.  I'm just waiting on Google to increase their API quota so I can add more users.  Hopefully people find it helpful.  I like the native Reminders app.

Comment: Update: Tasket its now available to everyone; just sign in with your Google account. Still working on a few bugs but its functional. Although, there are also some great new apps for task management so the native Reminders app is getting a run for its $$!

Comment: Andrew - it seems you pulled off Tasket, (or it is unintentionally offline). any plans to donate the source so someone else might continue? and if I may ask, what caused you to stop it (hosting bill I assume, but could be something else). I would have paid 2-5 dollars for this service (not sure if covers costs of hosting...)

Comment: @Andrew, it is a shame that Tasket service is discontinued... Any plans to resume it?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to be the bearer of bad news but no, not currently.

You may also want to read this [thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27480/how-can-i-sync-reminders-with-google-tasks) which appears to be the current thoughts on the matter

Comment: Sadly this is the best I've found as well. A real shame, I'd love to use Reminders instead of the uglier google tasks iOS apps or Springpad.

Answer (score 0):

I have not heard of a way to sync...but 2nd best would be to view them both in the same place. Fantastical gets great reviews for this...see [Fantastical](http://flexibits.com/)

Comment: A downside to this is the fact that you can't create reminders with Siri this way :( [Tasket](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/98060/7833) fixes that (theoretically)…

Answer (score 0):

Gtasks is subpar. The biggest reason I like iOS Reminders is it's one of the best things that SIRI does well. I use it all the time. If gTasks were capable of acting as an intermediary between Reminders and Google Tasks then it might be a good product, but at the end of the day, it's a stand-alone tasks app that does not take advantage of SIRI. This coupled with the deception of listing it as "free" on the AppStore but requiring you to pay for it later in-App...not cool. I am all for paying for a good app but give it to me straight. At the end of the day it does not have what I want in a tasks app.

Answer (score -1):

GTasks will allow you to manually import iOS Reminders to Google Tasks, but there is no 2-way sync.
http://itunes.apple.com/app/gtasks-hd-google-tasks-go/id428249408?mt=8&ls=1

Comment: Doesn't seem to be any way to sync gTasks with iOS Reminders to me.