# How do I sync Google Tasks to an iPhone?

Tags: ios, reminders

I can sync my mail and calendar to Google from my iPhone via the [GMail Exchange interface](http://support.google.com/mobile/bin/answer.py?hl=en&topic=14252&answer=138740), but my GMail task list is not synced. How can I sync my tasks so that they show up in the built-in Reminders app?

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't currently appear to be a way.  If you're willing to use an alternative to the built-in iOS Reminders, there's [gTasks](http://www.katans.com/).

There is more information in the answers to this duplicate question: [Sync Google Tasks with iOS Reminders?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/37556/sync-google-tasks-with-ios-reminders)

Comment: Actually, there are two questions already dealing with this subject:

- http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/37556/sync-google-tasks-with-ios-reminders

- http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/127784/what-is-the-current-state-of-syncing-google-tasks-and-ios-reminders

As far as I know, there is no solution to sync *Google Tasks* with *iOS Reminders* at this moment.

Comment: why do you recomend gTasks? Is it a reliable tool? Have you tried it?