# What is the current state of syncing Google Tasks and iOS Reminders?

Tags: iphone, ios, siri, reminders, google-sync

Right now Siri says "You don't have any reminders," whew. But then Google Tasks tells me I have at least 9 things to do today. Whoops.

Yes, I know this question has been asked before, but the answer is a moving target as integration with outside services gets tighter. And yes, I know there are third party services [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/connect/ios_reminders/google_calendar), for instance. And I know there are other apps that provide reminder/task integration with Google Tasks (I use GoTasks).

But...

I like Google Tasks because it is integrated with my GCal.  And it would be swell to have Reminders integration. Then Siri could schedule and access my tasks.

**What is the current likelihood I will be able to easily integrate iOS Reminders with Google Tasks?**

I suggest leaving this question open, to reflect the moving state of this integration. I will check this as answered if someone offers native or relatively simple integration.

Update: Awesome, I just got the "Popular question badge" because this question has has more than 1000 views. But uh, not awesome: Not one upvote? And only one semi-sorta-answer?  Hmm.

Answer (score 1):

**This service is no longer available as of some time in 2016, therefore the link is *broken*. Original answer preserved below for reference.**

This is as close to "native" as I could find: a service which provides Reminders sync, and imports them from Google.

- Sign in with a Google account
- Add the Tasket account on iOS via Setting > Mail, Contacts, Calendars
- You're all set!

http://**tasket**.mobi/faq

Comment: Well, though it is not native, you are right about it addressing the problem: "Tasket is service that solves one simple problem: Synchronize your Google Tasks (found in Gmail) with the Reminders app on your iOS device. Although you can get your Email, Calender and Contacts on your iOS device by adding a Gmail accoount, Apple didn't include support for syncing Reminders with Gmail Tasks."

Comment: Tasket is no longer working, I think.

Comment: Yep, Tasket's dead.

Comment: This is (would be) the Holy Greil of simple task management! No good news yet?

Comment: This is why native integration is important.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of IFTTT and Zapier.

Bizarrely IFTTT supports iOS reminders but not Google Tasks (https://ifttt.com/ios_reminders).

Zapier supports google tasks but NOT iOS reminders
(https://zapier.com/app/explore)

The trick is to trigger from IFTTT and send an email to Zapier which triggers on the email and then updates Google Tasks.  I've tested it and it works.  The biggest challenge is when you have multiple reminders lists.  In this case I have not found a good way to dynamically select the google task list from Zapier as it keys off of task list id and not task list name.  I suggest making a separate Zap for each reminder list.

Finally this doesn't solve the problem of doing the initial sync.  You can use the gtasks app for this.