# How to add reminder to ios 5 Reminder app from my PC?

Tags: iphone, applications, ios, windows

How to add reminder to ios 5 Reminder app from my windows 7 PC? or it will much better to sync Reminder to google calendar. I like location based reminder of Reminder app.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know there would be two ways.

**1. Outlook**

Reminders is synced through iCloud, so you should have iCloud installed on your PC. Here is an easy guide provided by Apple. You only really need to follow up to step 2 to sync Reminders; step 3 is to keep your Purchased Music from iTunes in sync too.

Reminders is synced through "Calendars and Tasks". You'll need Outlook 2007 or 2010 to sync.

**2. Web App**

The other option I can think of is adding your reminders directly to iCloud through the Web App. This is done by going to the [iCloud Website](https://www.icloud.com/). Sign in with the Apple ID you use on your iOS device and click on the "Calendar App" once signed in.

You should see your Reminders on the Right Column. If you don't, go to the `Action Menu` (the cog icon on the top right corner) and select `Show Reminders`. You can add new reminders by clicking on the `Action Menu > New Reminder`, or double-clicking on the bottom of your reminder list.

**Syncing With Google**

About syncing with Google, [this other thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27480/how-can-i-sync-reminders-with-google-tasks) might be useful.

BTW: I don't think you can add locations on Outlook or the Web App. I could be wrong, but I don't see the option.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Personally for the sync, first I use the iPad, I work with the iPad all the time so I used the app Beesy to make the sync Outlook Tasks with Reminders. So now, with the sync, I'm sur do not miss an important even because the sync is with my iPad but my iPhone and laptop too so is very convenient!